# Removing cartridge from tap problem

Tags: faucet

I have a dripping mixer tap, and trying to replace the cartridge.

I'm following some google/youtube videos and they say you have to remove a nut then the cartridge will come out.

After removing the tap head and casing there is no nut to remove

It is a brass circular piece with 2 notches, not sure how to remove this, or should it be removed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like Mike said, you need a special wrench to get that "nut" off your faucet. You will need something like this:

[image]

You can get them pretty cheap at home stores or plumbing supply stores.  Trace out the nut on paper and bring it with you to the store so you can get a match.

It looks like someone already tried to remove it by tapping a screwdriver placed in one of the slots. This can work sometimes if the nut is not too tight but you always have to be careful not to damage the threads because some sleeves screw down on them. Good luck.

Comment: has this type of wrench got a name? wondering what to google

Comment: Basically they're just called plumbing wrenches. Each company can have different ones for their products and will have different names.

Comment: Take a photo with a tape measure in the photo. Then take that to a local plumbing store I have a set with 4 or 5 sizes that fit inside each other I think that set only cost about 15$ . + definitely be careful if you don’t use something like this or make a spanner you may damage the fixture (using a punch and hammer as already noted) I have seen expensive fixtures ruined because equal force was not applied and cracked the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Buy or make a spanner that will fit into those two slots then undo the brass piece - either it will clear the plastic or the plastic parts will come out with it.